# React & CSS: How to override :root in css module in React?

Tags: css, reactjs, themes, jsx

Short question. I'm trying to build a theme selector for an app and was wondering how to change the :root of a css module in a press of a button in jsx.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to change a CSS variable (property) which is initially set in a :root pseudo class when the user clicks a button? [I wasn't sure what ':root of a css module' meant].

Comment: @AHaworth yes dude

Answer (score 0):

Update: I discovered something. I wonder if its ok to do it like this tho

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react'
const _settings = () => {
    function x() {
        document.querySelector(':root').style.setProperty('--primary-color-darkgreen', "red")
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={x}></button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default _settings
```

Comment: Actually i don't think that manipulating the DOM is correct here. React is building an own virtual dom which is then getting translated to the DOM. You should just use state and change the class (with the CSS needed in a separate file) to achieve your desired behavior.

Comment: @SaltukKezer I don't quite understand the part about changing classes with a separate file. Do I modify each one of the classNames with a ternary?